# ios: NSArray containsObject: NSIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm a little bit confused about NSArray containsObject method. Does this method compares pointers to objects or exactly content of them? To be more specific: i have got an array of NSIndexPath objects, created somewhere before, and now i want to check, if there is an NSIndexPath object with row = 2 and section = 1. If i write the following code, would it work?

```
[[self arrayOfPathes] containsObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: 2 inSection: 1]];
```

I've tested that code, and it worked for me, but i had some bad experience with comparison of pointers instead of object's content beforehand (btw, that code worked for me, and was approved for the app store, but late many of users reported about the bug made by it).

Comment: Have you read the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject: ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try looking in the docs for the NSArray method containsObject? It says:

> This method determines whether anObject is present in the array by
>   sending an isEqual: message to each of the array’s objects (and
>   passing anObject as the parameter to each isEqual: message).

So if the object in question implements isEqual to compare the setting of the object instead of comparing the address, it will work.

The docs on NSIndexPath don't tell you if it implements a custom implementation of the isEqual method or not, but I would guess that it does.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for your answer. I just was not sure about that and wanted to clarify it. Thanks.

Comment: And one more related question, just to be sure - if i make an NSDictionary with an NSIndexPath as a key, would NSDictionary's method objectForKey: return me the rite value, if pointers of NSIndexPath'es are different?

Comment: Ok, i've tried that myself, and that doesn't work. So how can i make it in the real project?

Comment: You posted 2 different things. It isn't clear what you mean by "i've tried that myself, and that doesn't work." Tried what" What doesn't work?

Comment: It's probably best to stick with NSStrings as dictionary keys. You use other object types as keys, but this is not typical, and some uses of dictionaries like property lists REQUIRE string keys.

Comment: Feel so stupid. I forgot that i should initialize the dictionary before usage... Thank u.

Comment: nonexistent objects don't tend to work very well. :)